# How does a WinForms .Net sub-application in a solution embed its app.config into itself?

Tags: winforms, app-config, configurationmanager

I am using a variation of [Jeff Atwood’s Unhandled Exception handler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7482/User-Friendly-Exception-Handling) it steps in when there is an Unhandled Exception in the application. It then logs the error, generates a screen shot and notifies the user.

When compiled in a solution the project generates an EXE that is called when needed. In updating the program I am using *Visual Studio 13* to edit the existing settings items in the project properties. In the code I use commands such as this from `ConfigurationManager`.

```
string appProduct = unhandledExceptions.Properties.Settings.Default.AppProduct;
```

I was happy to see that it worked and reflected the changes I made in the IDE. However I couldn’t find the settings in the solutions generated *confg* file (`MyApplication.exe.config`). I assumed it was reaching back to the other project folder for the `UnhandledExceptions.exe.config`.

I created an installer and installed it to a virtual machine.  My settings carried over, but again I could not see a *config* file.

It turns out the values are embedded in the executable `UnhandledException.exe`.

The project does not have any resources listed. Searching the web and *StackOverflow* looking a questions that want to do this, and there are a lot of them, it seems this was generally considered not possible and not desirable. Questions usually end in *“You don’t want to do that, it’s called config for a reason”.*

I may want to turn this off, so it is editable externally. The properties of app.config in both projects are identical.

What setting is making this possible after all? Is it a new capability with *Visual Studio 2013*?

Comment: A class library project cannot have a functional .config file.  Only the .config file of the EXE project is ever used.  Your code still works because it simply uses the default value, as recorded in the project's Settings.Designer.cs file.  Which is okayish, it is not like the user ever has a good reason to change the product name :)  What you are supposed to do is merge the class library's config entries into the EXE project's config file yourself.  It is not automatic and not very practical.

Comment: @HansPassant  I can change the user values in code. Changes to those values that are saved, write to a local copy of 'user.config' in the AppData application section of the user's folder just like the main application would.  It does create a separate section in that file, keeping it apart from the main application's updated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *Visual Studio* setting required. If you don’t want the user to have access to the configuration file, don’t include it in the distribution. One can always be added if the settings names are known.

In the description below ***application*** generically represents the name of the application being used.

I’ve found through observation some interesting things about the way *ConfigurationManager* works.
For *User* settings it will look in the following places in order of priority:

- *user.config* for the application in the user’s *AppData* area
- *application.exe.config* in the program folder
- *application.exe* itself

Each setting is searched for individually. If your application requests a setting that is not found in either user.config or the application.exe.config it will get it from the executable.

For *Application* settings it looks in the following places in order of priority:

- *application.exe.config* in the program folder
- *application.exe* itself.

There is no equivalent to *user.config* for application settings.

Opening the *application.exe* in the *Visual Studio* IDE does not reveal a resource for the configuration information.

*application.exe.config* is handy because it can be modified externally and used as a default value for new installations. Once a setting is overridden in the *user.config* the value in *application.exe.config* is ignored.

The same is not true for the ***AppSettings*** section, the older configuration method from *.Net 1.0*. If I delete the configuration file it does not have them in the executable.

These observations were made with *Visual Studio 2013 Update 4* and tested in *Windows 7 Professional* 64-bit. I suspect they are true in all versions.